# Building a bridge to the stars

Tags: space, materials, engineering

Could I, purely in quantity of material only, build a solid bridge to a star?

Ignore anything like strength, relative motions of systems, that is all taken care of, using lalalaicanthearyouium - this is not remotely based in any actual science.

All I want to know is whether there is enough material for a decently powerful race to build a solid bridge spanning actual light years from things they have lying around nearby, i.e. a solar system, a couple of stars - but not a whole cluster or galaxy.

The bridge should be along the lines of the classic film trope - "it looks like metal, but it's not any material we've seen before, Bob!" - that sort of solid.

Although using iron held together with lalalaicanthearyouium would also be fine if there is enough iron lying around. "My God, Bob, it's just iron ... but how can that be?!?"

Comment: Well... if your structure is thin enough, it sounds feasible. BTW i would use unobtanium, if i were you, or handwavium. Both are much more convenient.

Comment: I'm sure you were already aware, but [the idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator) is already be discussed, just in a smaller scale, at least for now.

Comment: Yup, I did know about space elevators; I'm not intending this to be remotely as plausible though :) I'm actually surprised how little material I need!

Comment: Oh, and don't forget: It totally has to be [3d-printed](http://www.livescience.com/52750-robots-build-3d-printed-bridge.html)!

Comment: The tricky part isn't getting enough material to build the bridge; it's *maintaining* it when any two given stars are moving relative to each other at a significant speed.  That's not a design requirement ordinary bridges have to deal with!

Comment: @MasonWheeler Such three dimensional thinking! Even if both ends are "stationary" wrt to each other, space will stretch between the two ends (think Dark Energy).

Comment: @MasonWheeler Ordinary bridges also have to deal with that as well, but at a much smaller scale.

Comment: Ok, since nobody else asked, I will: *Here's a question: why?*

Comment: Vanity project?

Comment: Neither the Earth, nor any star have fixed positions relative to each other, nor even fixed distances.  In space, everything is in motion.

Comment: In answer to your expected follow up question: By the time the first team have painted the first 100 thousand miles of the bridge, it's time for a new team to set off to repaint it. So there are 500 million teams equally spaced over the full length, slowly travelling along the bridge painting one side, then the other side on the way back. It takes a painter society 50 million generations between leaving one end and arriving at the other, so for most painters the ends of the bridge are mythical notions based only on the tales of passing bridge users.

Comment: @trichoplax An absolutely brilliant idea, which I hadn't thought of, and now can't use :)

Comment: @Whelkaholism of course you can use it... :)

Comment: @trichoplax Now I'm thinking the teams are setting off from both ends. One side paints the bridge military grey, the other ocean grey. CONSTANT WAR ENSUES. There are so many stories I can set on this bridge I'd never even considered :)

Comment: I added some new calculations in my answer, check it out!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**That is a surprisingly reasonable project!**

Let's dismantle the Earth, and use it as building material to Alpha Centauri. The Earth is $5.974 \times 10^{24}~\text{kg}$, and Alpha Centauri is roughly $4.13 \times 10^{16}~\text{m}$ away, so that is almost **150,000 tons of building material per metre**. That is enough for any bridge. Even if you stretch it all the way to the galactic centre, you still have about 20 tons of materials per meter.

Given a cost of about [£14,000](http://www.kgbanswers.co.uk/how-much-does-uk-motorway-cost-to-build-per-mile-on-average-in/2956542) per metre for a motorway, a bridge to the star will cost you 600 billion billion ($6×10^{20}$) £. (assuming the same cost...)

Happy building!

Comment: but only 33% of earth is iron.

Comment: This is going down in my book of cases where, against all odds, the stellar distance do *not* make something impossible!  That also suggests that the tensile strength of the bridge might be enough to prevent it from collapsing back into a planetoid!

Comment: The closest star to Earth is Sun. You should be able to keep the planet in place.

Comment: For comparison, this is larger than the UK GDP multiplied by the population of the UK ($2×10^{12}*6×10^{7} = 1.2×10^{20}$)

Comment: I'm outraged that my taxes pay for £14,000 per metre of motorway.

Comment: @CortAmmon the tensile strength won't be enough to prevent gravitational collapse. And the proof is that it has already happened: the Earth is big enough to be spherical.

Comment: @MichaelT: In the English language, a billion ceased to be a million million since the 70s (before then it was a million million in the British Empire but a thousand million in the US). It is a thousand million. Granted, some languages may have numbers that sounds like "billion" that means a million million but that's no longer true in modern English.

Comment: @MichaelT: in the short scale 600 billion billion is 600 quintillion. 600 long scale billion billion is 600 trillion.

Comment: Who owns the mineral rights to the core?

Comment: @Davidmh Gravitational collapse is typically modeled around the assumption of a large number of relatively free particles.  If you're taking the time to intelligently fuse the material into a bridge, I presume you take the time to ensure its strong directions are in line with the effects of gravity to stave off collapse.

Comment: You and @overactor answered at pretty much the same time, but I like the fact that you included an actual star as the destination and Earth as the raw materials - gave me a great grasp of the quantities. Thanks!

Comment: @CortAmmon: Did you really mean tensile strength, rather than compressive strength?

Comment: @LarsH \*sheepishly\* yes.... thank you for catching that!

Comment: @Davidmh see [my answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/34282/328).

Answer (score 18):

Yeah, ok, you've got your billion-billion tons of lalalaicanthearyouium, but:

## How long would it take?

I don't have very good data on this, but let's assume that the [1973 expansion to the Chesapeake Bay Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chesapeake_Bay_Bridge#1973_expansion) is a reasonable model (powers of ten are more important here, you'll see that even if I'm off by a full factor of 10 it won't really change much).  The bridge is 4.3 miles long and took 4 years to construct.

6920 meters in 1461 days, or about 4.75 meters per day (really 4.73, but 4.75 is a nice round number).  And that's assuming that a bridge is constructed from one bank, across the river, to the other and not bottom-up: remember, we're building with lalalaicanthearyouium which is both weightless and has an infinite tensile strength (not to mention plentiful, cheap, and as easy to work with as steel, if not more so).

The nearest star, the sun, is 149,604,618,000 meters away.  A little math and... 86.2 *million* years later you've got a bridge to the sun!

Job well done.

You're going to need some *serious* industry to shorten that duration.  You'd need thousands of sites building bridge segments and flying them into space in a near-continuous stream and that'd still only take you down to a tens of thousands of years.  The good news is that because lalalaicanthearyouium is weightless, you simply need to drive down the constructed portion of the bridge, to the end, maneuver the new section into place, bolt it down, then drive back down the other side (traffic flowing as a loop up and over the rising vertical spire of the bridge).

TL;DR, I'm pretty sure you won't be taking a [night train to Rigel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0765346443) any time soon.

Edit:

So I thought about this a bit more, and at the x1000 speed mentioned via multiple construction sites and combining the results, we get the following numbers:

- It still takes 86,200-ish years to complete
- Construction progresses at 4750 meters per day, or just under 200 meters per hour.
- This is also 0.2 km/h or about 4% walking speed.
- This means that if we scale up another 25 fold, our construction speed equates to a comfortable walking speed.
- Under the idea that The Anathema (see comments below) proposes of building from the *bottom*, someone could walk along the structure once it is half-finished and reach the far end at the same time it reaches the destination (walking the first half with the second half constructed behind them).  The trip would take 1,724 years.

  - Better pack a lunch.
- This still only gets us to the Sun. Reaching Alpha Centauri (nearest extra-solar star) increases the distance and build time 276,173.784 times.
- If we want to increase our build speed by the same amount, then our construction speed reaches 0.127% the speed of light...*assuming that the [speed of sound](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69238/what-is-the-speed-of-push-waves) within lalalaicanthearyouium is at least this value.*

  - Bad news, this is greater than the speed of sound in steel by two powers of 10 ([0.00127c ~= 1119 Mach](https://www.unitjuggler.com/convert-speed-from-c-to-Ma.html?val=0.00127), Steel: [17.78 Mach](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/sound-speed-solids-d_713.html)) and even greater than that of diamond (34.98 Mach) and beryllium (37.58).
  - Which would require our lalalaicanthearyouium to not only be weightless, but *unimaginably* dense/rigid [citation needed: cannot find a relationship between a material's properties and its speed of sound].

    - Which lead me to just learn that a neutron star can't exceed 3.2 solar masses in size or its density results in a material-speed-of-sound that exceeds *c*.  Turns out that [that's pretty darn accurate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_limit).
    - Oh hey, [science paper](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1988ApJ...333..880E/0000888.000.html) from 1988 that did some math and made a nice chart. The top half of that chart is the velocity of the longitudinal wave. 10<sup>9</sup> cm/s<sup>-1</sup> is just about 5% the speed of light.

Comment: But since it's weightless, it should be reasonable to build it from the origin, and simply have the new pieces push the rest of it closer to the star. Then you wouldn't have to fly all the way to the end. I wonder if that would work, considering that push occurs in an object at the speed of sound. What do you think?

Comment: @TheAnathema The effect on the calculation doesn't really effect anything.  You're still limited by how quickly you can move the pieces into place.

Comment: Night Train to Rigel isn't a good example--while that book doesn't explain how the system works later books do to some degree.  The trains aren't giga-engineering, the handwave is elsewhere.

Comment: @Draco18s By building them at the end, you're increasing some variables. Resources to fly the pieces to the end. Each ship would need to travel the increasing distance to the end of the bridge, and that costs resources - you need to build the ships that are great in number enough to have the continuous stream that you're looking for, and that might influence how much material you have available to convert to lalalaicanthearyouium. It might be more efficient to build it from the start and push it out to the sun. Or, even better, build it on both ends. This is all just word vomit, though. : )

Comment: @TheAnathema Remember that material resources are ignored and that the time calculation is based on a linear construction time.  So it really doesn't matter which end is being built on, either by pushing a weightless structure upwards or by extending the far end.

Comment: @TheAnathema I just did some math based on construction speeds relative to walking speeds and discovered really neat numbers. :)

Comment: @TheAnathema: Why would it help to build at both ends?  Unless there is raw material at each end to set up factories near...  Anyway, as you build it, the finished part of the bridge is moving at whatever speed towards the destination.  New pieces to be attached are accelerated to this speed (perhaps as a result of being extruded), and docked to the near end.  If connecting pieces serially is a bottleneck, build up sub-assemblies before taking a turn attaching something to the main bridge.

Comment: Variations in mfg speed -> change in distance to the near end, not change in speed of the whole already-constructed part.  Decelerating it to a stop near the end of construction will be *interesting*, because the speed of sound is so slow compared to its length.  (And because that's a *lot* of momentum.)  You will get crazy oscillations lasting years even with damping.  Still, this is probably easier than working on the bridge really far from the mfg site.

Comment: I am loving all the extra info in the answers to this question, so I'm going to continue to leave it open for a while longer because you're all awesome :)

Comment: @Whelkaholism some questions lead to answers that in doing the math lead to some really interesting discoveries.  IIRC Randal Munroe has a twitter feed for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that we are both moving in different directions be a problem?

Comment: @TheAnathema - it would only be weightless if it was in freefall around the Sun...

Comment: @HorusKol No it's weightless because it utilizes [Applied Phlebotinum](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AppliedPhlebotinum).

Answer (score 13):

### It's not completely ridiculous

For simplicity's sake, I assumed you're making a bridge that's one lightyear long, has a cross-section of one square metre and [plugged that into Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+lightyear+*+1+m+*+1+m). We're looking at roughly 9.461 quadrillion m<sup>3</sup> ($ 9.461 * 10^{15} $ m<sup>3</sup>) of material which corresponds to a solid sphere with a radius of 131.2 km.

If we consider that the [Death Star II](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star_II) had a diameter of 160km, I'd say what you're setting out to accomplish is not entirely without precedent.

You could for instance grab [15 Eunomia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_Eunomia), turn it entirely into lalalaicanthearyouium and have enought material to build yourself a whole lightyear of interstellar bridge.

### Won't it collapse under its own gravity?

Let's see. Imagine a bunch infinite amount of 1 metre wide lalalaicanthearyouium spheres lined up next to each other. We start by calculating the gravitational force the second sphere exerts on the first using Newton's law of gravity:

\begin{align}
F_1 & = G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2} \\
& = G\frac{m^2}{1^2} \\
\end{align}

For the third sphere's force on the first one we get:

$$
F_1 = Gm^2
$$

What we're getting here is an infinite sum, so let's write that out and see what it gets us.

\begin{align}
F_t & = \sum_{r=1}^\infty G\frac{m^2}{r^2} \\
& = Gm^2\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{1}{r^2} \\
& = Gm^2\frac{\pi^2 }{6}
\end{align}

This is great news, The gravitational pull of an infinite series of spheres lined up next to each other on the first sphere is equal to $\frac{\pi^2 }{6} \approx 1.645$ times the gravitational pull between the first two. Of course, a bridge is not actually a series of spheres, but this should not be a problem since this approximation work better when the two objects are further apart. at a few kilometres, there will hardly be a difference.

You can improve on this calculation by making the distance between the segments (except for the first one) variable, and scaling the mass with the distance between, so they still accurately represent slices of the bridge. And then take the limit of the distance going to 0:

$$
F_t = \lim_\limits{d \to 0} Gdm^2 \sum_r^\infty \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2}+rd)^2}
$$

Calculating this limit is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: One light year long?  That doesn't even get you out of the solar system by some measures (e.g. outer limits of the Oort Cloud).

Comment: @overactor: Build five of these and you can reach Alpha Centauri

Comment: The bridge requires the material of a *solid sphere* with r=131km; the Death Star is relatively hollow and with a radius of 80km.

Comment: @Brian maybe it's not a story about OUR solar system :)

Comment: @overactor This is great news indeed! I shall start building this bridge immediately!

Answer (score 5):

Other people looked carefully at the amount of materials required and found that it would not be unreasonable to make a "bridge to the stars."

However, there's more to this than just building the bridge.  You also need some sort of vehicle to traverse the bridge.

### Yes

#### Bridge Crawlers

In most ways the devices used to move stuff along the bridge to the stars would act like elevators (just like for a space elevator).

I assume that this would be the case for your bridge to the stars.

#### Eliminates Propellant Needs

The most important benefit of using elevator cars to crawl on your bridge to the stars is that it removes the need to bring along propellants - since the bridge becomes your propellant. You will still need to bring the other stuff you require to survive in space (life support, power, etc.).

#### Might eliminate the need to generate power

Depending upon how you make your bridge, you may be able to transmit electrical power through the *lalalaicanthearyouium* structure of the bridge. *Lalalaicanthearyouium* had better be a superconductor though or transmission losses will kill you, lol.

### Conclusion

Basically, not only are the material requirements reasonable, building one would actually make the travel easier.

We just need to pretend stellar motion doesn't occur :)

Comment: If you knew you weren't going to use this post to answer the question, why did you post it as an answer?

Comment: You should rephrase your answer. You can expand more on the need for power and energy since that does indeed count as a resource for building. You could have done so, but instead you prefaced your answer with "Not an answer." which is peculiar given the Stack Exchange guidelines.

Comment: I originally wrote it as a comment - but it seemed more significant and relevant to the discussion than a comment.  I'm thinking about how to redo it as a relevant answer.

Answer (score 2):

Say your bridge has 1 square metre cross section and a density of 1 metric ton per cubic metre. Then one lightyear of bridge would be approx $10^{16}$ tons. The Earth is about $10^{22}$ tons. If Earth was to contain a percent *unobtainium* and if it was dismantled to get material, it should work.

Comment: Unobtainium isn't much use for this project, what it needs is lalalaicanthearyouium!

Comment: Water is about one metric ton per cubic metre; which raises an important question.  Does unobtainium float?

Comment: @user16295 If you use a compound of lalalaicanthearyouium and handwavium most of the problems will simply vanish into thin air.

Answer (score 2):

**What would prevent your superstructure from rolling up to a giant *hank* of lalalaicanthearyouium** (*handwavium*) **under its own mass?**

---

I mean it has to be flexible to link two solar systems (which are of course in motion related to each other). I mean if it has the mass of 100kg/m, then it weights 4.0680272*10¹⁸ kg which is all gravitated to its center of mass. I would assume if it is strong enough to not brake apart, it would roll up in a spiral then entangle itself.

Comment: But if you add a reasonable percentage of anti-higgs to your unobtanium-handwavium-composite you still get a decent bridge but without this nasty gravity thing messing up a beautiful structure. :-)

Comment: @Burki Yes, some fine-tuned **anti-higgs** would help building the bridge - you wouldn't even need _unobtanium-handwavium-composite_ , you could use i.e. **PVC** since it would not collapse uder it's own mass and you could balance the amount of an anti-higgs to keep the whole structure apart.

Comment: true... but unobtanium-handwavium-composite looks so much cooler!

Comment: lalalaicanthearyouium has some suprisingly strong anti-Higgs properties :) Thanks for this answer, but I did state to ignore strength / motion etc. If there had been a i-laugh-in-the-face-of-science tag I'd have used it :)

Comment: @Whelkaholism If you ignore physics at all, just do it, but then what is the point of this question? You could handwave the amount of material you need away like all other natural-science issues.

Comment: It's so spread out that the forces will be weak.  Tiny, even.    The bridge isn't a spherical shell, so the simplification that it's gravitation equals the gravitation of a point mass at the center doesn't apply.  It's not even close to spherical, so it doesn't work even as an approximation.  **The gravity of the stars at either end acting on the the bridge will put it under tension.**  Since gravity increases closer to the star, every part of the bridge will be pulled away from every other part (tidal effect).  I haven't done the math either, but star gravity > bridge self-gravity for sure.

Comment: @mg30rg The seed of the idea behind the story is more magic realism than sci-fi. I simply wanted to know that it wasn't like 10 times as many atoms as exist in the Universe (yeah, I know, my maths sucks). I guess the discovery of a bridge that could only have been constructed from outside the Universe would have been a good plot device too. All I need is to work willing suspension of disbelief in for a non-technical audience.

Comment: @mg30rg I mean, it's a Worldbuilding.se question, not a Physics.se one. I think it fits on a site that also contains questions on the limits of the abilities of magic wizards, Santa and vampires :)

Comment: @Whelkaholism I didn't have concerns about this question not fitting physics at all - I could easily accept that. I had problems with asking a physics question while suspending physics. It is like asking "I know the speed of light can't be achieved but if it is achieved what would happen to the astronauts?", and of course there is no answer for such a question.

Comment: @PeterCordes Well, I have done the maths and you should consider that the force of gravity weakens proportionaly to the square of the distance, so distant stars can not balance gravity of a megastructure. The two stress points theory you have made only makes the bridge more instable; it will not only become a giant hank, but it will become a giant hank slowly falling towards the star with the bigger mass.

Comment: @mg30rg: What math exactly did you do? I don't see any gravity calcs in your answer for the point at which self-gravity overcomes sun-gravity.  The Sun masses 2E30kg, 12 orders of magnitude more your 4E18kg bridge. Gravity dropping off with 1/r^2 affects the bridge's self-attraction, too: none of its mass is close to the rest of its mass. The force on a tiny segment of the bridge at `x` from one end includes the force from both stars, and the force from the bridge from 0 to x (balanced by the bridge from x to 2x). Net f is stars + `integral(G*m*(dr*density)/r^2,  r = 2x..end)`, I think.

Comment: You can handle imbalanced stars by hanging a bigger asteroid from the end of the bridge that's subject to weaker gravity.  Even if you don't agree with my handwaving, you can overcome the bridge's self-attraction by hanging asteroids from the ends, deep in the gravity wells of the stars (where the GMm/r^2 gravity force is much stronger than anywhere else).  This is an unstable equilibrium, though, so active station-keeping is needed.  When the bridge drifts closer to one star, it's attracted even more strongly to that star.

Answer (score 0):

Several answers have addressed the numbers--you can build it.

What nobody seems to have touched is what good is it?  Bridges have an implicit assumption of gravity being normal to the bridge surface.  What gravity you will encounter is parallel to the bridge, not normal to it.  You have a strip of lalalaicanthearyouium to the stars that can only be climbed, not walked upon.

If you're going to do something I would think it would have to be a ladder, not a bridge.

(I'm ignoring the problem of a lack of fixed endpoints.  In reality that's going to make it useless anyway.)

Comment: Space elevators work by attaching cars that crawl up or down the surface of the strands of the elevators.  I assume that this would be the case here.  The practical impact is that it removes the need to bring along propellants since the bridge becomes your propellant.  You still need the other stuff (life support, power, etc.).

Comment: You might not even need to bring power, as it's possible to transmit electrical power through the *lalalaicanthearyouium*.  It'd better be a superconductor though or transmission losses will kill you, lol.

Comment: @Jim2B It makes a reasonable support for an elevator to the stars.  I was specifically objecting to "bridge", though.

Comment: I wasn't really critiquing your answer.  I just thought I'd provide that little bit of info.  I ended up creating a separate "answer" and putting that info into it.  However, it really isn't an answer to the question, just additional information to think about.

Comment: I think you may be underestimating the qualities of lalalaicanthearyouium somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

Really, this is just an upscaled space elevator.

Most others have already pointed out that it may be possible from a materials point of view, but I don't think anyone's pointed out what other issues you might have.

Let's look at an Earth-Moon bridge for a more local example:

One problem we have is that the Moon orbits at a different velocity to the Earth's surface - so anchoring it at this end could be a problem. The Moon itself is tidally locked, with the same face always pointing at Earth, but there is still a small wobble during its orbit, so anchoring might be easier there. Oh, and the Moon is receding (slowly) and the Earth's rate of spin is slowing, too (one is a consquence of the other).

Then, we have this giant ribbon of material undergoing gravitational attraction towards the Earth, gravitational attraction towards the Moon, and so it will be under massive tension. Not too mention, the Sun and other planets will have some gravitational influence.

---

Let's get back to the Sun-star bridge:

As as been mentioned - all stars are in relative motion to each other - but locally, this isn't all that fast.

One problem is that to prevent the bridge from just collapsing into the Sun, its will need to be in orbit around the Sun. I'm pretty sure the maths on this is going to get very complicated for an elongated body (compared to the relative small spherical bodies we're familiar with).

This in itself will setup tension along the bridge (some of the bridge is being pulled toward the Sun, some of the bridge is accelerating away from the Sun as it orbits).

Then, eventually, as the bridge is extruded out towards the other star, we're going to have to account for additional tension of the bridge being pulled in towards that star.

And then there's the gravitational effects of all the other local stars.

---

I think what all this adds up to is a mathematical nightmare of orbital mechanics...

Comment: Shouldn't build "from StarA to StarB". Rather build from the mid_point out towards each star, keeping the rate balanced against the two stars' gravities. Bridge shouldn't exactly "orbit" either star. Definitely a "mathematical nightmare", though.

Comment: You'd have to shift a lot of material to the mid-point... starting at one star or another, you can "extrude" the bridge out. Even from the mid-point, you're going to end up with two parts of the bridge under different gravitational influences - maybe orbit wouldn't be technically correct.

Comment: Yep, a lot. OTOH, it's much easier to avoid or vastly minimize the "orbit" problem. The varying gravities may be countered by controlling the rates that mass is added to either end.