# Retour on Santas Presents

Tags: technology, santa-claus

Okay, now it's December 27th, Christmas is done for this year. Santa delivered every present to every child on earth [and to some kids on the moon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/65579/colony-on-the-moon-how-fast-can-santa-deliver). But, you know, kids of today are very picky about presents.

Assume half of the kids world wide are picky as my niece, who goes of like an air raid alarm, if only the slightest thing is wrong in her present. So, the parents have to retour the presents and get the correct one in order to silence the kid.

Santa's work is not done!

He has to organize the biggest and most efficient retour service, to exchange all faulty presents until the beginning of the of the new year.

He cannot fly another round, his licence is only valid once a year, for safety reasons, because whole air corridors were locked down to avoid collision.

## How can he provide a most efficient retour system, to handle the incoming and outgoing packets?

Remember: North pole is the place to go for the presents and from there they shall be returned.

Santa's north pole base may be extended with any state of the art technology, airports, NASA style VAB... you name it and it is there

## Keep in mind: Nice and naughty aren't binary values. A child can be both, but not necessarily at the same time.

Comment: With all due respect, but if children are unhappy with things they have received as a gift they are spoiled little brats and perhaps a lump of coal would serve best to teach them some gratitude for what they get instead of installing a retour system.

Comment: @Hyfnae The lump of coal, is just a myth. Seriously, do you believe in a big red man in a reindeer hyperdrive mobile to give away lumps of coal?

Comment: Hmm, my advice is to tell your niece to stuff it and take away her presents. Seriously, it's a gift! Pretend to like it!

Answer (score 5):

If the child is picky about the gift, this mean he/she is no longer on the "good child" list and that means no gift at all. The gift will autocombust to leave a lump of ashes...

Answer (score 2):

A good child is grateful, a good child appreciates the gift, a good child writes a polite thank you letter even when they didn't get what they wanted.

Bad children get coal. Replacement presents are easy, a couple of lumps of coal will do. A good child can have the rejected present.

(I don't have children)

Comment: Point is: Nice and naughty aren't binary values. A child can be both, but not necessarily at the same time.